# Identify javascript closures with developer tools

Tags: javascript

I am currently developing a website that is pure javascript and relies heavily on the jQuery & jQuery UI libraries (this site is not intended for use by a general public, hence progressive enhancement is not a strict requirement for this project). I am encountering a significant memory leak on executing the following code:

```
oDialogBox = $("<div>...</div>");
/* Add useful things to the dialog box here */
oDialogBox.appendTo("body");
oDialogBox.dialog({
    /* Other dialog box settings here */
    close: function(event, ui) {
        oDialogBox.dialog("destroy");
        oDialogBox.remove();
        oDialogBox = null;
    }
});
```

At any given time in this dialog box, I am creating, removing and modifying a large number of instances of jQuery UI buttons, multiselects (per the Multiselect widget created by Eric Hynds) and on click event handlers. According to jQuery UI documentation, calling .remove() on oDialogBox *should* result in all child widgets being unbound and deleted. Yet my detached DOM tree shows a significant number of garbage elements that the GC isn't collecting.

It is highly likely I have missed a large set of closures that need to be finished off safely. How do I do the following:

1) How do I identify which closures are keeping a given detached DOM object alive (either in Firefox or Chrome)?

2) Assuming the complete set of closures is identified, does anything beyond nulling the variable need to be done to assure marking the DOM element for garbage collection?

3) I have also noticed my list of arrays stored by the page is giant and contains references to DOM elements not being gathered by the GC. Is there a documented best practice for cleaning arrays from javascript and allowing all elements to be marked for deletion? (Note: this is a current prime suspect for the source of the memory leak)

Comment: "*list of arrays containing references to DOM elements*" - might that be the reason for the DOM elements not being garbage collected? How do you inspect this list?

Comment: When using the chrome developer tools, I have been taking heap snapshots with the profiler tool. After running my test, almost 50MB of additional memory was taken up in the heap. This was identified by the profiler as being stored in "(array)" objects. Random inspection has found jQuery properties for elements in the Detached DOM tree. I have also found evidence of empty arrays that are not being collected. I am still trying to identify if any of the arrays I define in my code are hiding in the list of 10k+ objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that I don't have a great answer for #1.  I haven't found any really good tools for this myself, even given how good the development tools have become over the last few years.  The best advice I can give is to always keep things in the smallest scope you possibly can.  If things don't escape, it's generally easier to simply figure out where the references must be.

As to #2, there can be further concerns.  If the object referenced by variable `v1` closes over the free variables of some function, removing `v1` will not be enough to make them eligible for garbage collection if another variable `v2` closes over `v1` in some other function.  So I guess if you really mean the "complete set of closures", then you should be all set.  But this might get hairy.  Again, if most object have references only in narrow scopes, these problems are much less severe.

For #3, what sorts of arrays are you discussing?  If it's jQuery collections, then perhaps you simply have too many of them around.  The only reason I know for them to stay around for a long time is to bind event handlers to them, and that is almost always better handled by event delegation on parent elements.  If it's you're own custom arrays, do you really have a good reason to store references to them in arrays that last for any substantial length of time?  I've rarely found one.

Comment: When I initially read your response, my immediate reaction was "No, the array is completely necessary." But after thinking about it over the night, I'm really only using the array to maintain a dynamic list of special divs for form data collection when the user hits "submit". The same trick could probably be done with more extensive use of classes on the objects and the jQuery selector.

Comment: Another possibility is an array of their ids, if the elements have ids.  This is much lighter-weight, and might be more targeted than DOM classes.